# PostgreSQL: rename an unnamed partition?

Tags: postgresql, rename, partition

I created a table with monthly partitions, however I made a mistake with the initial partition.

When I browse the partitions in Data Grip it first one shows up as unnamed (see image)

[image: Partition list from Data Grip]

However, when selecting the partition tables there is tabled for this partition, named **abc_1_prt_2**. All the other partitions' tables are named something like **abc_1_prt_p202208**

Is it possible to rename the unnamed partition?

When I right-click on *partition*  in Data Grip and select **Rename**, Data Grip provides the following script:

```
alter table sam_tap.fct_tap_metadata rename partition "" to "'p201809'";
```

which gives the following error:

> [42601] ERROR: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"

Comment: There is no `rename partition` to begin with, you would need `alter table "" rename to p201809;`  (don't include special characters in a table name). But most probably the table name isn't really empty it's just your SQL client that can't handle that correctly. Try `select * from pg_partition_tree('sam_tap.fct_tap_metadata');` to view all partitions

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name

`alter table sam_tap.fct_tap_metadata rename partition "" to p201809;`
results in 
_[42601] ERROR: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"_. Seems like we're on an older version of PostgreSQL, as `pg_partition_tree` does not work for exist for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just FYI, in the end I dropped the table and recreated it with the correct partition name (and populated the data from a back-up).

I was not able to re-name the unnamed partition.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE "partition <unnamed1>'
RENAME TO whatever;
```

This assumes that there are no extra spaces anywhere in the name.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the name of the partition, it is just Data Grip's way to indicate that the partition is not named.

Comment: Then use a good client like `psql`. A partition cannot be unnamed; each table has a name.